# STS & Spring Integration multiple xml files and merged Integration Graph

Tags: graph, spring-integration, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, graph-visualization

I am working on a project using spring integration. I am using XML because I like the visualization of integration flow using Integration-Graph in STS. But because of reusing components and reorganisation flows in subflows in separate xml files, I would like to have a merged view in the graph.

As I remember the Spring Bean Graph it was possible to select configuration files as package for visualisations.

Is there a functionality for Integration, too?

Comment: I am not aware of such a feature, I am sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While that feature is not available in STS, we are working on a runtime visualization of a running Spring Integration application. Since 4.3, Spring Integration (when running in a web container or as a Spring Boot application with web support), can expose the runtime environment as JSON [see documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#integration-graph).

The [spring-flo project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-flo/tree/master/samples/spring-flo-si) has a sample (it's still a work-in-process) for visualizing the flow.

The application used in the readme is the the [file-split-ftp sample application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/file-split-ftp). Notice the required CORS bean definition (which will be made simpler in the next release).

Comment: As STS has support for distributed bean xml-configuration (defining a set) and merge it into the graph, why isn`t there a similar feature for Spring-Integration. Isn't it a similar requirement? Is there something planned on this way as well?

Comment: The big difference is the integration graph is a file editor not just a visualizer; I asked for this years ago and it never happened. Contributions are welcome! With the recent move to people preferring more java and java DSL configuration (which is much harder to visualize statically), the runtime visualization I mentioned is very cool. There has also been some work with a round-trip editor for the Java DSL but it's very early days.

Comment: Hey Gary, thanks for explanations. That`s why I used XML-Configuration to use that graph feature for documentations reasons and it could be very helpful. I will have a look on the mentioned Runtime Visualization. Thanks again and have a good week.